# AngularJS - Scope issue with modal view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I saw a lot of question about this area, but couldn't find one that solve my problem. For some reason, the ng-model in my modal view html, does not update according to it's view controller.

I have a controller which invoke a modal view ([using AngularUI modal view](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)) that way:

```
$modal.open({
                templateUrl: "createNewFeedWizard.html",
                controller: 'NewFeedCtrl'
            });
```

In the html file (which also contains the controller's view):

```
        <div class="panel-body" data-ng-controller="NewFeedCtrl">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="createNewFeedWizard.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 style="color: #1c7ebb">Add New Feed</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div data-ui-wizard-form>
                    <h1>RSS URL</h1>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div style="position: relative; top: 30%; left: 1%">
                            <span>Enter the RSS feed URL</span><br>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newFeed.url">
                            <span class="help-block">Some help text goes here.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </script>
        </div>
```

And my modal view controller is the following:

```
    .controller('NewFeedCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'httpService', 'logger', 'FeedLoader',
    function($scope, $location, $routeParams, httpService, logger, FeedLoader) {

        $scope.newFeed = {
            name: '',
            url: 'http://',
            application_id: '',
            id: isNaN(parseInt($routeParams.feedId)) ? 0 : $routeParams.feedId,
            rssFeed: {}
        };
    }
```

So I would expect that ng-model="newFeed.url" will translate into "http://", but unfortunately the input remains empty.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

So the problem caused due to one of my directive - data-ui-wizard-form - which enable [Jquery steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) for AngularJS. This is my directive:

```
.directive('uiWizardForm', function () {
return {
    link: function (scope, ele) {
        ele.steps(scope.wizardSettings)
    }
}
});
```

Any thoughts on what should I add to the directive in order to make it work?

Comment: you may need to set $scope with current scope `$modal.open({ templateUrl: "createNewFeedWizard.html", controller: 'NewFeedCtrl', $socpe: $scope });` while opening popup

Comment: But the current scope is not the NewFeedCtrl but the one which invokes the modal. Should I still set the scope as you said?

Comment: I'm not sure, you could try that

Comment: Just tried it, still no luck :(

Comment: put  $scope.newFeed    inside timeout function..

Comment: could you create same issue with plunkr?

Comment: Asaf maybe it's that extra `<div class="panel-body" data-ng-controller="NewFeedCtrl">` that's wrapping your HTML ? Try either removing it or remove the `controller: 'NewFeedCtrl'` in the $modal declaration.

Comment: what's this doing? `data-ui-wizard-form` if it's a directive it may be creating a new child scope. Try `ng-model="$parent.newFeed.url"` see if that works. Otherwise check your scope settings in the directive.

Comment: @OmriAharon I tries and it's not that.

Comment: @gonkan That it! When I remove it everything OK! but I need it and adding the $parent didn't help.

Comment: remove controller from your div, because you alreday loading it while opening popup

Comment: Your directive is creating an isolated child scope, you need it to inherit the parent scope. Try setting the scope setting in your directive to `scope: { newFeed: '=' }`

Comment: Also, here is a good primer on directive scopes: http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: @gonkan adding `scope: { newFeed: '=' }` didn't help. Any other ideas on how to keep the scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure why (and will be happy for an explanation) but this solved my issue:

```
.directive('uiWizardForm', ['$compile', ($compile) ->
return {
    link: (scope, ele) ->
        ele.wrapInner('<div class="steps-wrapper">')
        steps = ele.children('.steps-wrapper').steps()
        $compile(steps)(scope)
}
])
```

Comment: It looks to me that you are creating further child scopes here and compile is bringing them back in scope for you... solutions depend on what you want the directive to do... consider using a tempalte in your directive rather than using jQuery to manipulate the HTML... I'm only guessing though.